# Multiple choice probability

Tags: probability

I just got out of an exam, and wanted to know the probability of the following: There is 28 multiple choice for 5 options to choose from for each question.

What is the probability to get 1, 2, 3,..28 questions right if it was all randomly answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the probability to guess $k$ right answers through the Bernoulli's law:

$$P(k)=\binom{28}{k}\left({1\over5}\right)^k\left({4\over5}\right)^{28-k}$$

Answer (score 0):

We have two posible results in each question:

1)The answer is  correct (with probability 1/5)

2)It's incorrect (with probability 4/5)

It could be modeled as a Binomial experiment, supossing that each answer is indepentent, so

if N=number of correct answers

$$P(N=k)=\begin{pmatrix} 28\\ k\end{pmatrix}(1/5)^k(4/5)^{28-k}$$ for k=0,1,2,...,28.

Comment: i did computation for k=4 and k=5, and the probability for k=5 is greater...how is that possible??

Comment: Remember that the probability mass P is a function of k, and the PMF of a binomial distribution has a maximum that can be interpreted as the mode of the experiment. In this case the maximum is 5.